# HttpContext.Current is null when CacheItemRemovedCallback is raised

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have code in global.asax that sets some things in cache with CacheItemRemovedCallback.

When item is removed from cache, method in CacheItemRemovedCallback is raised.

The problem is, it cannot update the item in cache because HttpContext.Current is null (therefor Cache cannot be accessed).

Is there a workaround for this or am I doing this entirely wrong?

Framework is 3.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the Cache from the HttpRuntime type:-

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Add( ... );
```